# react component is undefined under <Popup></Popup>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

SOLVED:

Thank you all for helping. I realized in the library I used, the trigger={} is a pre-defined tool that seems only works with a button. I wrote my own Popup component instead and fixed the problem.

I am working on a group project, and I want to make a popup window. I installed `reactjs-popup`. The code below works:

```
import UsernameForm from "./UsernameForm";
function RoomContainer() {
  // ...
  return (
    // ...
    <div>
      <UsernameForm
        inputtedUsername={inputtedUsername}
        setInputtedUsername={setInputtedUsername}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, once I wrap `<UsernameForm />` under `<Popup></Popup>` like below:

```
import UsernameForm from "./UsernameForm";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
function RoomContainer() {
  //...
  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <Popup trigger={/* something to trigger the pop up window */}>
        <UsernameForm
          inputtedUsername={inputtedUsername}
          setInputtedUsername={setInputtedUsername}
        />
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got an error message saying:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

I tried to add `{}` on the import, didn't work.

Comment: I think you forgot to export your RoomContainer component

Comment: @davsto Accepting answers and voting are completely optional actions on Stackoverflow. Please don't ask other users to do anything that isn't required of them.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what or where the issue is, can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes complete component code including the exports and imports?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that a proper pop up trigger has been set.

```js
<Popup trigger={<button>Trigger</button>} position="right center">
    <UsernameForm
          inputtedUsername={inputtedUsername}
          setInputtedUsername={setInputtedUsername}
        />
</Popup>
```